# Extract affine part of SymPy expression

Tags: python, sympy

I have a sympy expression with one variable `x`, e.g.,

```
import sympy
x = sympy.Symbol('x')

f = 3*x**2 + 5*x + 7 + sympy.exp(x)
```

I'd like to programmatically extract the *affine* part of that expression, i.e., the part that does not depend on `x`; `7` in the above example. Note that some terms may be nonlinear.

Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you need to use [`coeff`](http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.6/modules/core.html#sympy.core.expr.Expr.coeff):

```
>>> import sympy
>>> x = sympy.Symbol('x')
>>> f = 2*(3*x**2 + 5*x + 7 + sympy.exp(x))
>>> f.coeff(x, 0)
14
```

If you have an expression with multiple variables, you may try [`as_coefficients_dict`](http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.6/modules/core.html#sympy.core.add.Add.as_coefficients_dict):

```
>>> import sympy
>>> x = sympy.Symbol('x')
>>> y = sympy.Symbol('y')
>>> f = 4 + 3 * (2 * x + 4 * y + 3 * x * y + sympy.exp(x + y) + 6)
>>> coeffs = f.as_coefficients_dict()
>>> coeffs
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {exp(x + y): 3, 1: 22, y: 12, x: 6, x*y: 9})
>>> coeffs[1]
22 # 4 + 3 * 6
```